# JQuery validation on URL using plug-in needs to be customized

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I am using JQuery validation plug-in to validate a form on my webdirectory site. I need to allow users to enter an URL in the form "www.url.com", but the plug in requires the user to type URL as "http://www.url.com".

Is there a way around it? Please advise. Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approach that you can take:

1. Just add new custom method to accommodate it:

```js
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("url2", function(value, element) {
      
      //just change below regex to your needs
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$/.test( value );
    }, 'Please enter a valid url address.');
```

And ensure your element put data attribute type like below:

```
<input id="myid" type="url2"/>
```

2. Override the plugin method for url validation like below:

```js
$.validator.methods.url = function( value, element ) {
  return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$/.test( value );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please mention what to put under Rules and Messages part.

Comment: For rules, in the first and second option it is the regex, adjust it according to your needs. I already give you an example. For enhanced version you could try: ```^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$```

Comment: And if you want to customise the messages, for first approach just change the text ```'Please enter a valid url address.'``` into your preferred message..

Comment: Hope that answered your question

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I tried the second approach which sort of resolved the issue except for the fact that it accepts even if some one types in "www.url.c" where c is just a letter instead of atleast 2 or 3. Please share ur insights about this.

Comment: Yes....like I said... you could adjust the REGEX to your needs...perhaps you could try the enhanced version mention in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi. Tried the enhanced version but it didn't perform the validation, throwing no error on entering invalid URL.